# How can I create a column of dates using the start and end dates from a table in Teradata using SQL?

Tags: sql, loops, date, sas, teradata

The table columns are "Product_Number", "Product_Name", "Start_Date", "End_Date"

Table in Teradata:

[image]

Output Needed:

[image]

Comment: Is the output a Teradata table or a SAS data set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's proprietary syntax, `expand on`, in Teradata to create *time series* using periods:

```
select Product_Number, Product_Name
 -- extract the start date of the period value
  , begin(pd) as new_Date
from tab
-- create a period on the fly and return one row per day
-- periods include the start, but exclude the end, thus end_date+1
expand on period(start_date, end_date+1) as pd
```

This assumes your example dates are in `mm-dd-yyyy format`, if it's `dd-mm-yyyy` you need to expand by month:

```
select Product_Number, Product_Name, begin(pd) as new_Date
from tab
expand on period(start_date, end_date+1) as pd by interval '1' month
```

Or to return always the 1st of month:

```
select Product_Number, Product_Name, begin(pd) as new_Date
from tab
expand on period(start_date, end_date+1) as pd by anchor period month_begin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
SELECT [PRoduct_number]
      ,[Product_name]
      ,[Start_date]
      ,[End_date]         
  FROM table_name
  union all
  select 
        [PRoduct_number]
      ,[Product_name]
      ,ADD_MONTHS(cte.[Start_date], 1 )
      ,[End_date]
      from 
  cte
 where  StartDate < End_Date

)


select * from cte
```

Comment: however you should be careful about max recursion. also I have to bring your attention to this article as well if this is too slow : http://www.sommarskog.se/Short%20Stories/table-of-numbers.html

Comment: There's no *max recursion* in Teradata, `sql` tag does not mean `sql server` or `t-sql`